# Linq wherein extension methods variable p errors

Tags: c#, sql, linq, extension-methods

I write this extensions method for wherein;

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereIn<T, TValue>(this IQueryable<T> query,
                        IEnumerable<TValue> values, params Expression<Func<T, TValue>>[] valueSelectors)
        {            
            return query.Where(BuildContainsExpression(values, valueSelectors));

        }
        private static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> BuildContainsExpression<TElement, TValue>(
                        IEnumerable<TValue> values, params Expression<Func<TElement, TValue>>[] valueSelector)
        {
            if (null == valueSelector)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector");
            }
            if (null == values)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
            }

            Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> predicate = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < valueSelector.Count(); i++)
            {
                var param = valueSelector[i];
                ParameterExpression genericParameter = param.Parameters[0];

                TValue[] enumerable = values as TValue[] ?? values.ToArray();
                if (!enumerable.Any())
                {
                    return e => false;
                }

                if (!enumerable.Any())
                {
                    return e => false;
                }
                IEnumerable<Expression> equals = enumerable.Select(value => (Expression)Expression.Equal(param.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));
                Expression body = equals.Aggregate(Expression.Or);
                Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> partialPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, genericParameter);

                if (predicate == null)
                    predicate = partialPredicate;
                else
                {
                    var orElse = Expression.OrElse(predicate.Body, partialPredicate.Body);
                    predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(orElse, genericParameter);
                }

            }

            if (predicate != null)
                return predicate;
            return null;
        }

predicate result is = {p => ((((Convert(p.Id) == 1) Or (Convert(p.Id) == 3)) Or (Convert(p.Id) == 5)) OrElse (((p.MemberId == 1) Or (p.MemberId == 3)) Or (p.MemberId == 5)))}

public class OrderDto { public string Id {get;set;} }
```

my input is:

```
var list = new List<int?> {1, 3, 5}; 
var orderList = Entity.Order.AsQueryable().WhereIn(list, p => p.Id, p => p.MemberId).Select(t => new OrderDto {Id =t.Id}); –
```

But I get this error;

> variable 'p' of type 'OrderDto' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the last line copied exactly as it is in your code?

Comment: What is your input and your expected+actual output? You are not showing your complete code.

Comment: yes predicate result is look like it. it look like true. i want to look like it my linq. but when i call this predicate in where i get variable 'p' of type 'OrderDto' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined that error.

Comment: my input is:
   var list = new List<int?> {1, 3, 5};          var orderList = Entity.Order.AsQueryable().WhereIn(list, p => p.Id, p => p.MemberId).Select(t => new OrderDto                                                                                                            {Id =t.Id});

Comment: Please add that to the question. Also, can you add the definition of you class OrderDto?

Comment: public class OrderDto
{
 public string Id {get;set;}
}

Answer (score 0):

You are re-using the parameters from the given expressions.

```
ParameterExpression genericParameter = param.Parameters[0];
```

When you create new expressions, you also have to create new parameters.

```
ParameterExpression genericParameter = new ParameterExpression(...);
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18920396/261050) for more information from the master.

Comment: can you explain it ?  what i write new ParameterExpression(...); inside it ? regards

Comment: ParameterExpression x2 = new ParameterExpression();
                    x2 = param.Parameters[0];
                    predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(orElse, x2);

look like it ?

Comment: @Ben No. Like thatn you are still re-using the same parameter object. Create a new one which basically is a copy of the original. And see the link I added.

Comment: predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(Expression.OrElse(predicate.Body, partialPredicate.Body),predicate.Parameters[0]);

i write it in your shared link but i get same error again.